# TableView is not shown in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableView as a part of Stack View, but it doesn't appears on the screen

Here is the view:

[image]

Here I define the cells

```
class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,
UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    let list = ["Milk", "Honey", "Bread", "Tacos", "Tomatoes"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(list.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }
```

And also I override the `viewDidLoad()` method with this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

The structure of view looks like this:

[image]

where Table View itself has the following setting:

[image]

I don't get any errors and build is successful, but still I can't see the table on the screen (all other elements are presented), what could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but 1) the code in `viewDidLoad` is redundant if the connections are made in Interface Builder 2) `return` is not a function, remove the parentheses (`return list.count`). 3) Don't create cells explicitly, reuse them (`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)`). And where is the table view in the image?

Comment: do you set constraints properly for the table and implement heightForRowAt for cell height or use dynamic ??